# why is a lamp socket labeled "FOR TEMPORARY USE ONLY"?

Tags: socket, lamp

i am hanging a ceiling lamp which came with an cord set only rated 60W -- insufficient for my purposes. poking around in my parts bins, i found a rubberized E26 socket rated something like 660W, but labeled "FOR TEMPORARY USE ONLY". what does this rule mean, and can i use the socket anyway?

Comment: It's frequently the rest of the lamp that can't take the heat, not the cord.

Comment: I have flagged this to be migrated to DIY.se, the home improvement stack exchange.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams agreed, but I assert that it is not the case with this lamp. i won't install anything underrated, of course.

Comment: This is common on temporary outdoor lighting strings and their replacement sockets. It's a reminder to the user that they are not designed or approved for permanent outdoor installation.

Answer (score 1):

It likely means that it is NOT designed or constructed for CONTINUOUS use and/or to be built INTO some kind of fixture.  It can handle the heat dissipation only when out in the free air, and with intermittent use. Perhaps no more than 2 or 4 hours at a stretch, etc.

Comment: i have seen the label "not for continuous use" plenty of times on machines with moving parts, but never on electrical parts; you think this is a synonym?